# Calendar problem and identifying free slot

Tags: javascript, algorithm, calendar

I'm trying to solve an interval calendar problem.

> Given busy slots as a data-set in a person's outlook  calendar  and
> the time required for a meeting (eg: 45 mins) write a method to find
> an open available slot for scheduling a meeting.
>
> **Input:**
> per1: (1,5) (10, 14) (19,20) (27,30)
>
> per2: (3,5) (12,15) (18,21) (23,24)
> **Output:** (6,9) (16,17) (22,22) (25,26)

I'm trying to see how I can solve this problem using:

A) Vanilla JavaScript (ES5 / ES6)

B) Using Data-structure like Interval trees etc.

I'm thinking maybe combine both of the calendar's and sort them in ascending order of start time and then start looking for a slot? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Need your advice/suggestions on the same.

Comment: What are the constraints on the time and space complexity?

Comment: Can you explain? Can you make an assumption and run with the problem?

Comment: `(1,5)` is a tuple of absolute hours, right? i.e `1am - 5am`?

Comment: Yes. that's correct  It's 0-24 hours. So If i'm asked for an hour slot in between then it should return the time or the range where it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's a tuple of absolute hours and only two people involved, you could maintain a state array of length 24. Run a loop to mark all the hours where p1 and p2 are busy. You will be left with an array of hours where both of them will not be busy and then extract the absolute gaps between such intervals. Here is a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/r9nq63tk/1/) which handles the marking of the busy hours.

```
let freeHours = new Array(24);
// Mark the busy hours
let intervals = [];
for(let hours = 0; hours < 24; hours++) {
  // Find the ranges where the hours have not been marked and push it to intervals
}
```